# Button inside form triggers http post but it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

I produced an html form that contains some buttons which should not post the form. They are only supposed to do some javascript action. But when these buttons are clicked they trigger a post request. The html code of the buttons looks like this:

```
<button class="btn" id=some_id>
</button>
```

Nothing special as you can see. Is there a way to prevent these buttons from posting the form?

I used

```
$('.btn').bind('click', function() {
    some_js_code
});
```

to bind some js functionality to the buttons.
**Solution:**

```
$('.btn').bind('click', function() {
    some_js_code
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can we see the JavaScript that the button should execute along with how the event handler is bound, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an onClick handler and return false to prevent the default behaviour. For example:

```
<button class="btn" id=some_id onClick="alert('do stuff'); return false;">
</button>
```

Although as Anthony Grist pointed out, inline attributes aren't a great way of doing things.

Comment: thanks a lot. `return false` wasn't there in my function. Now its just doing the js action and not posting anything. It is not necessary to do it inline.

Answer (score 0):

should there not be something like `onclick="javascriptfunction()"` ?

Comment: 1. Don't link to W3Schools because it's [awful](http://w3fools.com). 2. You should be binding event handlers using JavaScript, not inline attributes in your HTML.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Oh right, thanks for that, as you can guess I'm new enough so I know no better! I'll check out those other sources

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

> Inside a  element you can put content, like text or images. This is the difference between this element and buttons created with the  element.

So, you still want to add the `type="button"` if you really want it to treat as a dummy button without post.

You mention you are using JavaScript so you could also set either

`cancelBubble = true` [MSDN cancelBubble property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or

`event.preventDefault()` [jQuery preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)